# batch/epoch in Keras model.fit

Tags: keras

Say one has 450 data points for training, and one sets the batch size at 20 with epochs at 50. So one will need 1,000 data points to train the model with the model.fit command in Keras. Since there are only 450 data points, how does Keras handle this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your assumption of 1000 data points required is wrong.

Comment: You are probably right. Do these 450 data points get reused in a circular way?

Comment: Yes, that is what models are trained, they see the data multiple times. Batching just means they see parts of the data at a time.

Answer (score 0):

First to be clear: epochs has nothing to do with data points and batch_size.

Now forget about epochs. You have 450 data points, you set your batch_size=20. So the model will pick 20 data points in each training process for weights update, and in your case the last time the model will pick 10 data points to finish the total 450 (450%20=10). You can also see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153531/what-is-batch-size-in-neural-network) for an explanation of batch_size.

Epoch is on the outside. Epoch basically determines how many times you want to repeat the above process, i.e., each epoch will go through all the 450 data points in the way you set your batch_size.